# Primitive indentation in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

Is there a simple primitive indentation mode for Emacs that would do the following:

1. When I go to new line (Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>), copy whatever white space used for indentation for above line
2. When I press Tab, insert indentation character(s) that can be configured (spaces/tabs) right there where I pressed Tab. Just insert spaces/tab, DO NOT DO "smart"-indentation.
3. [optionally] When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, remove one indentation character from the beginning of the current line
4. [optionally] Do indent/unindent selected blocks.

The question is: Does a mode like this exist? If, what is the name of it?

I don't want to start discussion on "Why do I need this behavior?" and I do not need "smart" alternatives for reasons beyond this topic.

I just want a plain stupid mode...

Emacs has been there for ages. Someone somewhere at some point of time must have asked this question and probably written a mode for it.

I went through lots of "indentation-related" topics... nothing there. Everyone just insists on "you should obey Emacs, not Emacs should obey you".

Comment: hmm.. by default emacs should do your 1 and 2

Comment: @Patrick OP request is "indent when press tab" not the auto indentation. so emacs by default doesn't indent by pressing `RET`

Comment: @kindahero: Oh wait, I misread. I withdraw my previous comments.

Comment: @kindahero, not exactly. It indents with spaces regardless of what was used on previous line. And Tab inserts spaces too..

Answer (score 4):

There you go, I just wrote it: https://gist.github.com/mishoo/5487564

Answer (score 2):

**1.** While in `fundamental-mode`, you could rebind <kbd>RET</kbd> to `newline-and-indent`

```
(local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

**2.** To make <kbd>TAB</kbd> insert tabulation/spaces instead of indenting, you should customize the `tab-always-indent` variable :

```
(setq tab-always-indent nil)
```

To choose between tab and space indentation, customize the `indent-tabs-mode` variable.

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)   ;; for tab-based indentation
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil) ;; for space-based indentation
```

I don't know of any standard way of doing points **3.** and **4.**, but it should not be too difficult to develop small custom functions to do this.

Comment: 1) It's the same as C-j. It does not preserve much desired whitespace characters, it does indentation.

Comment: 2) `(setq tab-always-indent nil)` is actually really nice :) Thanks!